# Erro 403 em Localhost XAMPP

Tags: xampp

Bom, sempre funcionando tudo normalmente no XAMPP em localhost, de repente ao iniciar o XAMPP o mesmo me retorna o erro 403, com esta mensagem:

```
Acesso Proibido!

Você não tem permissão para acessar o diretório requisitado. Pode não      existir o arquivo de índice ou o diretório pode estar protegido contra leitura.

Se você acredita ter encontrado um problema no servidor, por favor entre em contato com o webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1h PHP/5.4.31
```

Verifiquei o que poderia ter acontecido, vi algo relacionado  a VirtualHost, mas, não consegui implementar com sucesso.

[Meu http.conf](http://pastebin.com/7GsnDAnP)

Comment: Boa noite, olhando o `DocumentRoot` e o você usou `DocumentRoot "D:/Desenvolvimento/htdocs"`, isto não é a instalação padrão do Xampp, provavelmente você esta tentando mudar as coisas. Recomendo que instale do zero e no padrão. Pois do jeito que esta nós ficamos muito no "chute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido usando a soluçao encontrada em [Power-pixel](http://www.power-pixel.net/t49355-acesso-proibido)

No httpd-xampp.conf, troquei as linhas:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Por

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from 212.124.114.48
 Allow from all

 ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

NO Mac OS funciona assim:

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Trocar por:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
     AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Reiniciar todos os serviços.